# ¿Cómo saber si un job se está ejecutando en sql server 2008?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

Necesito verificar por sentencia SQL si un job se está ejecutando antes de forzar el procedimiento que tiene que realizar dicho job.

Comment: No has dado muchos detalles. Y me parece curioso que incluyas la etiqueta `asp.net` (¿que tiene que ver con la pregunta?). ¿Puedes dar mas detalles específicos por favor?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que la aplicación en la que estoy trabajando es en asp.net vb y utilizo el dev express y para la ejecución necesito la sentencia sql y si por alguna razón no se ejecuta el job por un botón debe poder ejecutarse desde la aplicación. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podés probar esto

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 
      FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs J 
      JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity A 
          ON A.job_id=J.job_id 
      WHERE J.name=N'Nombre del Job' 
      AND A.run_requested_date IS NOT NULL 
      AND A.stop_execution_date IS NULL
     )
/*Hacés lo que tengas que hacer si está en ejecución*/
ELSE
/*Hacés lo que tengas que hacer si NO está en ejecución*/
```